# php - foreach function and dynamically update an xml file

Tags: php, xml, foreach

I'm using this code to dynamically update an xml file,

my problem is that I'm confused about how to apply the order of the actions to do:

```
<?php

$files = scandir('./resources');
sort($files);
foreach($files as $file){
    if(is_dir("./resources/$file") and $file != "." && $file != ".."){
        myFun($file);
    }
}

$simplexml = simplexml_load_file('map.xml');

function myFun($scannedTitle){

    $tags = get_meta_tags('./resources/'.$scannedTitle.'/index.html');
    $scannedDescription = $tags['description'];


    $items = $simplexml->xpath('channel/item[@id="'.$scannedTitle.'"]');
    $items = $items[0];

    if($items->title[0] == $scannedTitle){

    }else{
        $items->title[0] = $scannedTitle;
    }

    if($items->description[0] == $scannedDescription){

    }else{
        $items->description[0] = $scannedDescription;
    }

}

$simplexml->saveXML("map.xml");

?>
```

The code was working, but now I changed the order of the functions and it does no longer work..
I can't understand in which order I have to perform the actions...

Here my "map.xml" file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
  <item id="red">
    <title>red</title>
    <link>http://website.com/resources/red/</link>
    <description>descriptionRed</description>
  </item>
  <item id="green">
    <title>green</title>
    <link>http://website.com/resources/green/</link>
    <description>Description of the green page.</description>
  </item>
  <item id="blue">
    <title>blue</title>
    <link>http://website.com/resources/blue/</link>
    <description>Description of the blue page.</description>
  </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: Is the xml file already created? Cause I don't see you test to see if it exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a variable scoping issue how `myFun()` is going to process `$simplexml` which is created outside the function.

i think that it will work this way by passing a reference for `$simplexml` in the function

```
 <?php
 $simplexml = simplexml_load_file('map.xml');

 $files = scandir('./resources');
 sort($files);
 foreach($files as $file){
     if(is_dir("./resources/$file") and $file != "." && $file != ".."){
         myFun($file, $simplexml);
     }
 }


 function myFun($scannedTitle, &$simplexml){

     $tags = get_meta_tags('./resources/'.$scannedTitle.'/index.html');
     $scannedDescription = $tags['description'];


     $items = $simplexml->xpath('channel/item[@id="'.$scannedTitle.'"]');
     $items = $items[0];

     if($items->title[0] == $scannedTitle){

     }else{
         $items->title[0] = $scannedTitle;
     }

     if($items->description[0] == $scannedDescription){

     }else{
         $items->description[0] = $scannedDescription;
     }

 }

 $simplexml->saveXML("map.xml");

 ?>
```